# Anchor menu close after link click

Tags: javascript, function, menu, click, hamburger-menu

I have a menu full of anchor links, which I got from: https://codepen.io/jpag82/pen/jAZjvV - my code looks like:

```
<div class="cnt__nav">
      <nav>
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#head" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#foot">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
      </nav>
 </div>
```

I combined this menu, with a smooth scroll script, which I got from: https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Both of these scripts are working, and aside from using anchor links, I haven't touched the either script. What I'd like to do is close the menu or run `toggleClass('is-open')` when a menu item is clicked.

I added a line to the JS that I thought would work, but when I added the smooth scroll, this function stopped working (just on the`.cnt__nav a` selector):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#cnt__nav-trigger, .cnt__nav, .cnt__nav a').click(function() {
           $('.nav-trigger').toggleClass('is-open');
           $('.cnt__nav').toggleClass('is-open');
           $('.cnt__nav a').toggleClass('is-open');
      });
});
```

I am guessing the `click` function in the smooth scroll is overriding the behavior of the links, causing `$('.cnt__nav a').toggleClass('is-open');` to stop working.

Is there a way I can mesh these two scripts together so when a link is clicked the menu closes?

The current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cnt__nav-trigger, .cnt__nav, .cnt__nav a').click(function() {
        $('.nav-trigger').toggleClass('is-open');
        $('.cnt__nav').toggleClass('is-open');
        $('.cnt__nav a').toggleClass('is-open');
    });
});




$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.cnt__nav a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.cnt__nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else {
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

The current HTML:

```
<!-- MENU -->
<div class="cnt__nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#head" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#main">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#foot">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- NAV TRIGGER -->
<div id="cnt__nav-trigger">
    <div class="nav-trigger">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1s7qfp9c/

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: My first thought is that you have conflicting bindings.  Taking the selector `'#cnt__nav-trigger, .cnt__nav, .cnt__nav a'`, the third selector is a child of the second selector.  So the logic is going to process the click on the a element, toggleing the class, and then the click event will bubble up to the parent which will process the click, and toggle it back.

Comment: does `$('.nav-trigger').toggleClass('is-open');`  and `$('.cnt__nav a').toggleClass('is-open');` necessary? I've removed them and it looks fine to me. check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kcvpraf/

Comment: @UmurDinçer `$('.nav-trigger').toggleClass('is-open');` changes the three lines to an X and `$('.cnt__nav a').toggleClass('is-open');` is what I tried to use to close the menu when the links are clicked. This function did work until I added the smooth scrolling.

Comment: @JoshRodgers I see, just remove `.cnt__nav` from selectors. Check my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kcvpraf/1/

Answer (score 0):

As @UmurDinçer was writing a solution I came up with one of my own...

Remove `$('.cnt__nav a').toggleClass('is-open');`, which looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cnt__nav-trigger, .cnt__nav').click(function() {
        $('.nav-trigger').toggleClass('is-open');
        $('.cnt__nav').toggleClass('is-open');
    });
});
```

Then I modified the JS, on line 5, I told it to remove the `is-open` class - which looks like:

```
$('.cnt__nav a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.cnt__nav a').removeClass("is-open active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

This fixes the issue because it's removing the `is-open` class, which causes the menu to close.

Comment: @UmurDinçer has a solution that works and is the accepted answer, just posted this here, so if someone else needs to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

@UmurDinçer came up with the solution...just remove `.cnt__nav` from selectors. Posting it here so I can select it as the answer.